# Printing invoice in different custom language

Tags: magento-1.8, invoice, pdf, language, locale

I have one website with multiple store views for different languages. All store views have same products, but use different front-end languages which are stored in locale.

When someone orders from *German store view*, **Sales=>Invoices=>(invoice #)=>Print** will print a *German PDF invoice*. I would like to be also able to print all PDF invoices in *English language* for accounting. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 5):

Some information for you on this:

The language is set in the `getPdf()` method of `Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Pdf_Invoice`. You will see that the locale and store are set according to the invoide data:

```
Mage::app()->getLocale()->emulate($invoice->getStoreId());
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore($invoice->getStoreId());
```

What you could do is to extend this functionality and add maybe a second button to your admin-backend which always generate the english invoice.

Be aware that `emulate()` needs a store id. If you don't have an english store, this won`t work.

In this case you could try to remove the first line `Mage::app()->getLocale()->emulate($invoice->getStoreId());` from your rewritten-method and also the revert back `Mage::app()->getLocale()->revert();` at the end of the function which sets the locale back to the last one before emulation.

Comment: Here is a little tweak I did, in my case some stores had different languages but the invoice had to be issued in the language that the store was located. here is how to set it up: `switch ($invoice->getStoreId()){case 1: $langcode=1; break;  case 2: $langcode=1; break; case 3: $langcode=1; break; case 4: $langcode=5;  break;  } if ($invoice->getStoreId()) { Mage::app()->getLocale()->emulate($langcode);Mage::app()->setCurrentStore($langcode);  }`